# How to call ffmpeg with Java - umlauts?

Tags: java, ffmpeg, processbuilder

I am using the Java ProcessBuilder to call FFmpeg to capture a single window on my screen on Windows 7 using this command:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
  "path\\ffmpeg",
  "-f", "gdigrab",
  "-i", "title=" + "title of window",
  "path\\out.mp4"
);
```

With most windows this works fine and I don't have any problems. But when I try to capture a window with an umlaut (like ÄÖÜ) in its title, I get an error that FFmpeg could not find that window. The same happens when starting FFmpeg using the Windows console.

Does FFmpeg have a problem using umlauts and is there a way to capture windows with umlauts?

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is not in window title. The problem is in windows shell that does not support letters others than English ABC. Check whether ffmpeg can read its configuration from file instead of command line.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this myself but I hope that this will work for you if you pass parameters via preset file instead of command line.

Take a look on section "7.1 Preset files" in the following document: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-Preset-files-1

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the preset files, but it didn't work. Maybe I've done something wrong, but I don't know where. After reading some blogs and other guides, I think that preset files just work for codec informations and not for information like the title in gdigrab.